# How can I utilize the capabilities of an AngularJS directive to defer rendering content until a click event?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In our rental application, we make an API call that populates an array, thus triggering an ngRepeat. This creates a list of divs that show basic information about the rental property.

Clicking on a property expands the div and then *another* API call is made to populate an interior ngRepeat with a list of tenants. Some of these properties have up to 100 tenants listed (past and present are included). The tenant divs themselves are also expandable, and this reveals the majority of the functionality. You can download rental agreements, view history, etc. All of this functionality is a single directive made up of a number of ng-includes.

If you're still following, there's an outside ngRepeat and an interior ngRepeat with a huge directive inside of it.

```
<div ng-repeat="properties in property_collection track by property.ID>
    *code removed*
    <div ng-repeat="tenant in property_tenant_collection track by tenant.ID>
    *...code here...*
    <div tenant-menu></div>
```

The directive `tenant-menu` and all of the ngIncludes and watchers that come with it are rendered when you expand the list of properties. They just aren't visible yet. Clicking on the tenant in the list just changes the height of the div, thus revealing the interior menu.

The performance implications of the way this UI was designed are absolutely dire. There's over 15,000 watchers on the page for elements that you can't even see. Taking action on one tenant fires the digest loop for all of them for no reason. It takes under a second to retrieve the necessary data, but almost 20 seconds to render a list of 60 applicants. I've removed the directive completely (which means nothing happens when you click on a tenant) and the loading & rendering time goes from 20 seconds to 2-3 seconds.

I'm not sure how I can achieve this, but is it possible to defer attaching this directive until the tenant is clicked? I don't want clicking on the tenant div to just change the height and reveal what's inside, I want to append the entire directive right then and THEN expand the height. Ideally, when the click event is fired again and the tenant is collapsed I would also be able to destroy any watchers and clean up after myself.

Whew.

Edit: The infamous sliding directive is pasted below. I think it's strange that a click event is being bound inside, but perhaps this is an O.K. code pattern in Angular. I have a hunch that I may be able to leverage the compile, postlink, and prelink functions along with the accepted answer. I inherited a bit of legacy code I think.

```
angular.module('jnjManagement.directives').directive('slideableTenant', function($compile, tenantService) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var targetX, contentX;

        attrs.expanded = false;
        element.bind('click', function() {
            if (!targetX) targetX = document.querySelector(attrs.slideToggleTenant);
            if (!contentX) contentX = targetX.querySelector('.slideable_tenant_content');
            if (!attrs.expanded) {
                contentX.style.border = '1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0)';
                var y = contentX.clientHeight;
                contentX.style.border = 0;
                targetX.style.height = 'auto';
            } else {
                targetX.style.height = '0px';
            }
            attrs.expanded = !attrs.expanded;
        });
    }
};
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally you would have a property directive and a tenant directive and you would indeed only load the content of the expanded element when it was clicked. I would make use of Angular's $compile.

```
$scope.clickHandler = function(){
    $('expanded-element').append($compile('<detail-directive></detail-directive')($scope));
};
```

Of course you would want to clean out elements when they are collapsed, too, but it sounds like you have a good grasp of performance considerations.

Comment: Oh my goodness, this worked perfectly!!

There is some delay when you click on a tenant, I assume this is because it's being rendered and data is being fetched. I'm updating my question with the full directive (missing your code snippet above). If you have any pointers on how I can leverage postlink, prelink, and compile to fetch my data, append the menu, and then expand the div I would be *extremely* grateful

Comment: Glad to help. I usually just use link. It is a bit hard to help without more concrete details. I do not know how complex the markup is for each of these nested tenants and it may be involved enough (e.g. tons of double curly braces...) to cause a significant delay and could be in need of cleanup. Also, have you inspected the xhr response time? Maybe there is a delay there that can be massaged out. If backend improvements are not possible, then you could request/compile/append records in smaller batches just so that the UI is useful while rendering the full recordset.

Comment: I think I was able to figure it out alright. It appears there's some delay between when `$compile` finishes and the next line of code executes. I tested this theory by wrapping the code snippet responsible for changing the height of the div in a `$timeout` set to 500ms. This was enough to remove the stuttering and provide a better experience. In production, I'll execute this code after the `tenantService` returns it's promise. You've been a perfect, perfect help.